# How to change colour of the boxes in my waterfall chart and remove y-axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

How do I change the colour of the boxes in my waterfall chart to the colour green? This is my first time making a waterfall chart in ggplot and so I just can't seem to figure out where to put the fill = "lightgreen" section of the code in. I also want to remove the y-axis labels as I have included the percentage increase in the box already. I have attached my current code along with the intended graph. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[my current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkDt0.png)

[my intended graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJdXg.png)

```
Percent = c(.01,.015,0.015,0.02,0.025)

testdata <- data_frame(Year, Percent)
testdata %>%
  mutate(val = cumsum(Percent),
         lag = c(0, lag(val)[-1])) ->testdata


ggplot(testdata)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = Year - 0.45,
                xmax = Year + 0.45, ymin = lag, ymax = val)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = Year, y = val, label = scales::percent(Percent)),
            vjust = ifelse(testdata$val < testdata$lag, -0.2, 1))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  ggtitle("Salary Increase")+
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 2):

Include `fill =` in `geom_rect` to specify the colour. Add `theme()` and call `element_blank()` for against axis line, axis title and axis text.

```
ggplot(testdata)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = Year - 0.45,
                xmax = Year + 0.45, ymin = lag, ymax = val),
            fill = "#23b14d") +
  geom_text(aes(x = Year, y = val, label = scales::percent(Percent)),
            vjust = ifelse(testdata$val < testdata$lag, -0.2, 1))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  ggtitle("Salary Increase")+
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't upvote your answer because Im still a new member but I appreciate the help a lot!